# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x^n}dx$ is convergent if $0<n<4$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x^n}dx$ is convergent if $0<n<4$

Let $f(x)= \frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x^n}$ then the function has discontinuity at the points $x=0 ,\infty$

Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^{n-3}}$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}{x^3} = 1$

Now $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{x^{n-3}}dx$ is convergent as $n-3 <1$.

I don't think this part is correct...

We see that $\int_{a}^{X}\sin(x)2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})dx$ is a bounded integral and $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x^n}$ is a bounded function on the integral $[a,\infty]$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\phi(x) = 0$

Then $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\frac{1}{x^n}dx$ is a convergent integral by dirichlet's test.

Comment: Dirichlet's test doesn't work without modification for an infinite interval. $f(x)=1$ is uniformly bounded and $g(x)=1/x$ is non-negative decreasing, but $\int_1^\infty f(x) g(x)\, dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$g(x)=\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))=\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{x^n}$ is decreasing to zero for any $n>0$, so $\int_{\color{red}{1}}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos x)}{x^n}\,dx$ is convergent for any $n>0$. On the other hand $\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))$ behaves like $\frac{x^3}{2}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin, so $n < 4$ is needed to ensure the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\color{red}{1}}\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos x)}{x^n}\,dx$.